# How to extract train data back from combined data set of both train and test data?

Tags: r, dataframe

I started the code by reading a train data file and test data file (They were already splitted). Then I combined them to save time and effort so the modifications are applied to both. Then I want know to extract the train data back from the combined in order to perform a special plot on it.

```
train <- read.csv('Downloads/train.csv', sep = ',')
test <- read.csv('Downloads/test.csv', sep = ',')
combin = rbind(train, test)
train = combin[1:nrow(train)]
```

This is the line of code that is not working when should be. The error displayed is: Error in `[.data.frame`(combin, 1:nrow(train)) : 
  undefined columns selected. 
But the number of column are identical for combin set and for the training set

Comment: Are you missing a comma ?or just do `combin[train,]`?

Comment: Where do you mean?

Comment: Here: `train = combin[1:nrow(train),]`?

Comment: omg thank you a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how to reproduce your error:

```
iris1<-iris[1:10,]
iris[1:nrow(iris1)]
```

This returns:

> Error in `[.data.frame`(iris, 1:nrow(iris1)) : undefined columns selected

Explanation:
Subsetting this way requires selecting either rows or columns. We can select all columns as follows for the specified number  of rows.

This works:

```
 iris1<-iris[1:10,]
 iris[1:nrow(iris1),]
```